# What are the meaning and usage of quodsi?

Tags: conjunctive

quodsi is a conj. meaning "but if", with "adversary force". Does it lead a conditional clause or a concession one? What does "but if" mean actually? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

*Quodsi* is just one example of how *quod* can precede a conjunction. It is simply a convention to spell it as one word if the conjunction is *si*, but not in other cases, and a convention, I believe, disparaged by many (including certain dictionaries). Similarly, you can occasionally read *quod nisi, quod ne, quod utinam, quod cum* etc. (for a long list of examples, see [Forcellini: *Quod* ¶ 9](http://www.lexica.linguax.com/forc.php?searchedLG=quod)).

This usually happens at the start of a sentence and serves to connect it to the previous one. It has an “adversary force” in the sense that it signals that the new thought which will now follow is somehow opposed to the one expressed immediately before, provides a counterpoint to it, puts it in perspective, or such. It is similar to *sed* or *autem*. So instead of *si autem Romam veniam* you could also write *quod si Romam veniam*.

Like *but* in English, the adversary force is often weak and seems more to keep the train of thought going. In fact, I'd say that "but if" is almost always bound to be a mistranslation for *quodsi*, and something like "now if," or simply "if," is better suited.

Also note that when you encounter *quod* followed by a conjunction, it is also possible (and probably far more likely) that it is a relative pronoun (*quod si fieret etc.*), which then has nothing to do with all these considerations.

Comment: Thanks. What kind of clause does it lead?  Does it lead a conditional clause or a concession one?

Comment: @Tim *quodsi* and *quod nisi* always introduce a conditional clause.

Comment: does "but" not mean opposition between the main and conditional subordinate clauses?

Comment: @Tim In the case of "but if," it means opposition between the whole conditional construction and the preceding text.